# how to get the id of the current object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want be able to do current_user.collaborators to get all the collaborators that the current user has. Meaning, all the users (aka collaborators) of all the tasks the current user is the owner of. and that's why I went on filtering ( the collaborations table to only get the collaborations records where current user is the owner of and then get the collaborators via the has_many collaborators naturally because of the previous filter.
while trying to filter by using `self.id` in the query, I'm getting the following error when I'm calling `User.first.collaborations` in Rails console :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<Collaboration::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fb41c802460>)
```

Any suggestion about what I should use/do to get to my goal please? Thanks for your help.

**User class**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :tasks
  has_many :collaborations, -> {joins(:task).where("tasks.user_id = ?", self.id)}
  has_many :collaborators, through: :collaborations, class_name: "User", source: :user
end
```

**Collaboration class**

```
class Collaboration < ApplicationRecord
  validates :task_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Task class**

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  validates :content, presence: true
  validates :label, presence: true

  belongs_to :user #owner of the task
  has_many :collaborations
  has_many :collaborators, through: :collaborations, class_name: "User", source: :user
end
```

Comment: `Undefined local variable or method 'id' for...` what is the full error?

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
  class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :collaborations, -> {joins(:task).where("tasks.user_id = ?", self.id)}
  end
```

It's important to note that `self` in the `has_many` lambda doesn't point to `User` instance, so it's not the way to get the id. I guess that you have a has-many relation to `Task`, but you want to call this relation `collaborations`, right?

You can write:

```
has_many :collaborations, class_name: 'Task'
```

and it'll work. [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) - section "Options"

Comment: I'm doing this so that the current user has only the collaborations where he's the owner the tasks and not all of them. I'll try tonight as I'm at work at the moment. just by adding the class_name it will suffice to get the current user id ? is that what you're saying ? why the lambda doesn't point to User ?

Comment: when you call `current_user.collaborations` with the code defined in my answer it will return only the tasks for the current user.

Comment: ok cool ! I'll try it out and will let you know. I was a bit skeptical about the fact that I had to add code (the lambda) to only the get those collaborations but I knew I Rails should do it for me...but looks like I was missing something. Will let know the outcome. why the lambda doesn't point to User instance though ?

Comment: just tried and I actually get only the tasks for the current user like you said. What I want to do is the following. I want be able to do current_user.collaborators to get all the collaborators that the current user has. Meaning, all the users (aka collaborators) of all the tasks the current user is the owner of. and that's why I went on filtering the collaborations table to only get the collaborations records where current user is the owner of and then get the collaborators via the has_many collaborators naturally because of the previous filter. what do think please ?

Answer (score 1):

self will be considered as User.id, while what you need is user object and its id of that object, you need to change your code little bit

remove has_many relationships with collaborations and write method for fetching records

```
def collaborations
  User.joins(:task).where("tasks.user_id = ?", self.id)
end
```

and call that method with user object

```
user = User.last
user.collaborations
```

and you will get collaborations for that particular user

Comment: here's what I wanted to do actually : `Collaboration.joins(:task).where("tasks.user_id = ?", self.id)`. so thanks because you gave me a hint. and then I wanted to have all the users (aka collaborators) where the current user is the owner of the tasks via `has_many :collaborators`. have a look at my last comment on the first answer I've had for my question. but thanks again.

Comment: glad you got your answer, always happy to help , although my answer is not much likely what you need. @NeimadTL

Answer (score 0):

You can't use self in the `has_many` association.

In order to have access to the user object when building the query, the user is passed as a parameter to the block. So basically, what you can do is:

```
has_many :collaborations, -> (user){joins(:task).where("tasks.user_id = ?", user.id)}
```

Now you can call `User.last.collborations`
This should work.

Go through this [link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for more info.